# plot.predict() or predict.plot() functions cited in literature, but no longer exists

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to use `predict.plot` or `plot.predict` (I've seen both of them referenced on various websites and I don't know which one is right).
However, in R, neither of these are valid functions. I don't know if I'm missing a package or if the sources I'm using are outdated in terms of the functions being referenced.

[This site](http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~tpminka/courses/36-350.2001/lectures/day30/) is using the function

It's very old. Can someone familiar with stats help me figure out how to do this with the latest version of R, or help me figure out how to get `predict.plot`/`plot.predict` to work?

Answer (score 6):

This is a user defined function. The author of the course you linked to provides it online:
[Link to R script](http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~tpminka/courses/36-350.2001/code/regress.r)

Comment: And any other functions you may need seem to be contained in the scripts [here](http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~tpminka/courses/36-350.2001/code/)

Comment: Thanks. I thought that might be the problem. This is outside the scope of my current course so I am trying to teach myself. I am curious how you determined that the code for the function was on the webpage and how you found the code. There is no mention (that i saw)  that this is user defined and also no mention that the code is on the page under any name (that i saw).

Comment: @user1800340 Well, I knew that this is not a base function nor in one of the major packages. I looked at the page you linked to and it did not mention any packages, but seemed to assume that the students know this function. Thus, I looked at earlier lectures and there it was mentioned that the function is provided by the teacher. From there it was easy to find [this page](http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~tpminka/courses/36-350.2001/) and continue from there.

Comment: Note that many R functions involving fitting functions have methods for `predict` which easily allow you to create a bunch of plottable data.

Answer (score 1):

The S3 dispatch system for functions in R examines the class of the first argument and then calls a function with the name `func.class`. In this case the author has defined several `plot.predict` functions: `predict.plot.data.frame`, `predict.plot.lm`, and `predict.plot.formula` which are then given the arguments on hte basis of the class of what is (first) in the argument list. The plot.predict function is just this:

```
predict.plot <- function(object, ...) UseMethod("predict.plot")
```

The "good stuff" is in the other three functions at the link Roland provided. I do think the author's use of a dot in the name for the generic function is a bit confusing. One might have expected there to be a class "plot" for which there was a generic function `predict`, but that is not really the case here, although you might find it interesting to just type: `methods(predict)` .After you had loaded the R script on that website you could find those various functions using:

```
 methods(predict.plot)
#[1] predict.plot.data.frame predict.plot.formula    predict.plot.lm
```